# How to use a class to print out elements of a list that contains transactions?

Tags: python, function, class, python-datetime

I'm trying to write a script that acts as a crypto program that generates a pseudo price of bitcoin, saves the bitcoin into a wallet, and monitors buying/selling transactions done by the script into a ledger, all via a menu. I've already created other classes (`Wallet`, `MyDate`, `GetLive`) that work to store bitcoins, display the live date and time, and generate a random live price for bitcoin per activity (buy/sell/deposit). For the `Ledger` class, I set up an empty list, `trans`, that acts as an empty list that will store each transaction done via the `append` statement, and have the `history()` function set up so that it prints out each transaction in the `trans` list. When I try to perform this, all it prints out is just the statement "Transaction History" and not the list of the buy/sell transactions, but when I use the `print` statement within a `for` loop to print out the list, things come out twice, which confuses me. I even tried replicating this in the "buy" and "sell" options, and they correctly show how I want the transactions to show up. I think there's something I'm not understanding properly, as I feel the solution is likely simple for this. Does anyone know the best way to go about setting up the `Ledger` class to properly print out the transaction history?

I have my whole coding displayed below for the crypto program:

```
from datetime import datetime

import random

balance = 75000  # This provides the user with $75,000 to invest.
num_coins = 0  # This is the amount of BTC the user starts out with.
z = 0  # This initializes the seed value for the random price for bitcoin that is determined by the GetLive() class.
trans = []  # This will be the empty list to which the buy/sell transactions will be added to.


class Wallet:  # This class will 1) store the ticker symbol for the bitcoin 2) store how many coins the user has
    # 3) prints the information out, including ticker symbol (BTC) for the coin and number of coins currently in wallet,
    # and 4) use a setter function to add coins to wallet and a getter function to fetch number of coins in wallet.
    symbol = "(BTC)"

    def getinfo(self):
        print(self.symbol, " : ", self.num_coins)

    def set_coins(self, x):
        self.num_coins = x

    def get_coins(self):
        return self.num_coins


class MyDate:  # This class returns both the date and time.
    def __init__(self):
        self.now = datetime.now()

    def dmy(self):
        self.now = datetime.now()
        dt = self.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        print("Date:", dt)
        return dt

    def hms(self):
        self.now = datetime.now()
        t = self.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print("Time:", t)
        return t


class GetLive:  # This class generates a random, live price for Bitcoin.
    def price(self):  # This method will as a pseudo random price for bitcoin (between 55-65K)
        random.seed(z)  # This sets the initial random seed that will be used to generate a random price for bitcoin
        return random.randint(55000, 65000)  # Returns a random live price for bitcoin


class Ledger:  # This class defines the Ledger as a class that will store buy/sell transactions and print the history.

    def __init__(self):
        self.trans = []

    def add(self, tran):
        self.trans.append(tran)

    def multiadd(self, *tranargs):
        self.trans.extend(tranargs)

    def multiadd2(self, tranargs):
        self.trans.extend(tranargs)

    def getTrans(self):
        return self.trans

    def history(self):  # This prints the history of the buy and sell transactions, including date & time.
        d = MyDate()
        print("\nTransaction History\n")
        for i in self.trans:
            for buy in i:
                print("On", d.dmy(), " at ", d.hms(), ", you bought " + str(buy), "" + Wallet.symbol, "for $",
                      buy_amount)
            for sell in i:
                print("On", d.dmy(), " at ", d.hms(), ", you sold " + str(sell), "" + Wallet.symbol, "for $",
                      sell_amount)


# Here, this is where the main section of the Bitcoin program is to be run.

while True:
    current_price = GetLive()
    L = Ledger()
    print("*********  Menu  ************")
    print("    0  - Price of Bitcoin", Wallet.symbol)
    print("    1  - Buy  ")
    print("    2  - Sell ")
    print("    3  - Deposit cash")
    print("    4  - Display # of bitcoins in my wallet")
    print("    5  - Display balance")
    print("    6  - Display transaction history")
    print("    7  - Exit")
    i = int(input("Please enter your choice: "))
    if i == 0:
        print("\nCurrent price of Bitcoin", Wallet.symbol, "= $", current_price.price(), "\n")
    elif i == 1:
        buy = float(input("\nEnter how much BTC you want to buy: "))
        buy_amount = int(current_price.price()) * (float(buy))
        print("\nThe total cost for " + str(buy) + " " + Wallet.symbol + " is $", buy_amount, ". Transaction complete."
                                                                                              "\n")
        if buy_amount < balance:
            d = MyDate()
            balance -= float(buy_amount)
            num_coins += float(buy)
            z = z + 1  # This changes the random seed value so that the GetLive class will generate a new random price
            trans.append([d.dmy(), d.hms(), ", you bought", buy, Wallet.symbol, "for $", buy_amount])
            print("On", d.dmy(), " at ", d.hms(), ", Bought " + str(buy), "" + Wallet.symbol, "for $", buy_amount)
        else:
            print("\nError: you have an insufficient balance...\n")
    elif i == 2:
        sell = float(input("\nEnter how much BTC you want to sell: "))
        sell_amount = int(current_price.price()) * (float(sell))
        print("\nThe total value for " + str(sell) + " " + Wallet.symbol + " is $", sell_amount, ". Transaction "
                                                                                                 "complete.\n")
        if num_coins > 0:
            d = MyDate()
            balance += float(sell_amount)
            num_coins -= float(sell)
            z = z + 1  # This changes the random seed value so that the GetLive class will generate a new random price
            trans.append([d.dmy(), d.hms(), ',', "you sold", sell, Wallet.symbol, "for $", sell_amount])
            print("On", d.dmy(), " at ", d.hms(), ", Sold " + str(sell), "" + Wallet.symbol, "for $", sell_amount)
        else:
            print("\nError: you have insufficient coins...\n")
    elif i == 3:
        cash = float(input("\nEnter how much cash you want to deposit: $"))
        balance = float(balance) + cash
        z = z + 1  # This changes the random seed value so that the GetLive class will generate a new random price
        print("\nYou deposited $", cash, ". Your new balance is $", balance, "\n")
    elif i == 4:
        print("\nYou currently have", num_coins, Wallet.symbol, "in your wallet.")
    elif i == 5:
        print("\nCurrent Balance: $", balance, "\n")
    elif i == 6:
        for y in trans:
            print("     >> ", trans)
        # L.history() This is supposed to display the list of buy and sell transactions
    elif i == 7:
        exit(0)
    else:
        print("Wrong input")
```

And this is what comes out as I attempt each option, including the `Ledger` class in option 6:

```
*********  Menu  ************
    0  - Price of Bitcoin (BTC)
    1  - Buy  
    2  - Sell 
    3  - Deposit cash
    4  - Display # of bitcoins in my wallet
    5  - Display balance
    6  - Display transaction history
    7  - Exit
Please enter your choice: 0

Current price of Bitcoin (BTC) = $ 61311 

*********  Menu  ************
    0  - Price of Bitcoin (BTC)
    1  - Buy  
    2  - Sell 
    3  - Deposit cash
    4  - Display # of bitcoins in my wallet
    5  - Display balance
    6  - Display transaction history
    7  - Exit
Please enter your choice: 1

Enter how much BTC you want to buy: 0.5

The total cost for 0.5 (BTC) is $ 30655.5 . Transaction complete.

Date: 12/19/2021
Time: 22:28:25
Date: 12/19/2021
Time: 22:28:25
On 12/19/2021  at  22:28:25 , Bought 0.5 (BTC) for $ 30655.5
*********  Menu  ************
    0  - Price of Bitcoin (BTC)
    1  - Buy  
    2  - Sell 
    3  - Deposit cash
    4  - Display # of bitcoins in my wallet
    5  - Display balance
    6  - Display transaction history
    7  - Exit
Please enter your choice: 2

Enter how much BTC you want to sell: 0.2

The total value for 0.2 (BTC) is $ 11440.2 . Transaction complete.

Date: 12/19/2021
Time: 22:28:33
Date: 12/19/2021
Time: 22:28:33
On 12/19/2021  at  22:28:33 , Sold 0.2 (BTC) for $ 11440.2
*********  Menu  ************
    0  - Price of Bitcoin (BTC)
    1  - Buy  
    2  - Sell 
    3  - Deposit cash
    4  - Display # of bitcoins in my wallet
    5  - Display balance
    6  - Display transaction history
    7  - Exit
Please enter your choice: 6
     >>  [['12/19/2021', '22:28:25', ', you bought', 0.5, '(BTC)', 'for $', 30655.5], ['12/19/2021', '22:28:33', ',', 'you sold', 0.2, '(BTC)', 'for $', 11440.2]]
     >>  [['12/19/2021', '22:28:25', ', you bought', 0.5, '(BTC)', 'for $', 30655.5], ['12/19/2021', '22:28:33', ',', 'you sold', 0.2, '(BTC)', 'for $', 11440.2]]

Transaction History

*********  Menu  ************
    0  - Price of Bitcoin (BTC)
    1  - Buy  
    2  - Sell 
    3  - Deposit cash
    4  - Display # of bitcoins in my wallet
    5  - Display balance
    6  - Display transaction history
    7  - Exit
Please enter your choice: 7

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: On each iteration of your main loop, you create a brand-new `Ledger` object.  Any transactions that were recorded in the previous Ledger are thrown away.

Comment: Note that you are calling `d.dmy()` (which is incorrectly named, by the way) and `d.hms()` twice in two lines, and those print data as well as returning it.  That's why you see "Date:" and "Time:" twie.  Unless you are debugging, those utility functions should not print anything.

Comment: @TimRoberts I see, so when both of those are called, that's what's causing the double appearance of the date & time. Upon closer inspection, I think you're right about the incorrect calling of those functions. If I didn't want the "Date:" and "Time:" to not show up, but only when reporting for the transactions, do I just simply not include the print statement within those functions?

Comment: @jasonharper Oh, that's not good, I wasn't even aware that those transactions were being discarded whilst having the main loop being done. If that's the case, would moving that outside of the loop have it create it only once, or would it have to be maybe created elsewhere?

Comment: The key is that `d.dmy()` and `d.hms()` should RETURN the date/time strings.  They should not PRINT it.  It's up to the caller to decide what to do with the strings.

Comment: I see now what you're emphasizing, both of those do correctly return them as intended. Now I feel rather silly for not noticing that sooner. I didn't plan on having them show up in the first place, but it thankfully served as a good debugging tool for verification.  Since both of these return as strings, is it possible that both can be associated with each separate transaction result?